# Jquery Colorbox is displaying binary of Amazon S3 image instead of actual image

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, colorbox

I am using [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).

Just trying a simple example to get images from S3 loading when the thumbnail is selected

Example HTML:

```html
<a class="fpg"  href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/image">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/image"/>
</a>
```

Example Javascript:

```js
 $(".fpg").colorbox({ rel:'fpg',current:false});
```

The thumbnails load fine. But when I click on a thumb and colorbox starts to the load the real S3 image I got this error.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am running this on a local server.

So I changed the CROS config of the S3 bucket to the default

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Now when I load up the image in colorbox, it just loads a whole bunch of binary. I can see PNG IHDR which I suppose is part of the binary.

Does anybody know how to properly load an S3 image?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's late but today i had a similar issue and i solved by using the html attribute, 
adding a setting like this:

```
 html:'<img src="'+$(this).attr('href')+'">'
```

when building colorbox.

You are simply telling to fill the preview with that html, of course you will need to keep the reference you want to apply colorbox to ending up doing something like

```
$('.classIwantToApplyColorboxTo').each(function(){
$(this).colorbox({
html:'<img src="'+$(this).attr('href')+'">'
               });
});
```

This trick could solve even XMLHttpRequest errors.